# How to use library with Web Components in Vitepress

Tags: vitepress

**Edited 2023-11-05:** Added `<ClientOnly/>` to make the issue with the `import` more obvious. In response to @laplacetw's answer.

I have an existing library with Web Components ([custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements)) which I'd like to use in Markdown files in Vitepress.

```html
<script setup>
import 'my-library/my-button'
</setup>

# My button:

<ClientOnly>
<my-button></my-button>
</ClientOnly>
```

Everything works fine in dev mode, and the component renders correctly. But when I run the build, I get an error message:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

How can I tell Vitepress to treat the entire library as "Client Only" and not try to import it during server side rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Edited 2023-11-06:

As mentioned in [#2367](https://github.com/vuejs/vitepress/issues/2367#issuecomment-1579328711), the VitePress maintainer said we need to wrap custom elements with `if (!import.meta.env.SSR) { ... }` or `if (inBrowser) { ... }` :

```js
// ref. https://vitepress.dev/guide/ssr-compat#conditional-import
    
// .vitepress/theme/index.js
/** @type {import('vitepress').Theme} */
export default {
  // ...
  async enhanceApp({ app }) {
    if (!import.meta.env.SSR) {
      const plugin = await import('plugin-that-access-window-on-import')
      app.use(plugin)
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you are using or demoing components that are not SSR-friendly (for example, contain custom directives), you can wrap them inside the built-in  component :

```html
<ClientOnly>
  <NonSSRFriendlyComponent />
</ClientOnly>
```

ref. https://vitepress.dev/guide/ssr-compat#clientonly

Comment: Still, I need to import my component in the setup script. So the not SSR-friendly component still is being imported on the server, trying to use web component APIs which are unavailable, and hence breaking the build.